Spring security migration to spring security 6
I'm getting really confused about the new Spring Security matchers. My current code (SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter):
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .antMatcher("/some/endpoint")
        .addFilterBefore(new CustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

What would be the equivolent with SecurityConfiguration? I got this far, but it seems not to work as expected:
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) throws Exception {
    return http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
               .authorizeHttpRequests(authz ->
                    authz.requestMatchers("/some/endpoint").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
               )
               .addFilterBefore(new CustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
               .sessionManagement(sessionManagementConfigurer -> sessionManagementConfigurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
               .build();
}

I see now most of my calls to open URL's like /actuator/health are blocked.
I also read in the migration guide:

In Spring Security 5.8 and earlier, requests with no authorization rule are permitted by default.

What is the best approach?

Does this answer your question? Securing actuator endpoints except /health

Thanks for your suggestion. It is different. I gave health as an example, but I have many more endpoints. Actually only one endpoint is protected, others are open.

Then you have to open all others, too. Just add the other ones. Your own answer is bad practices, you should not permit "any request". However, your old code is also bad practice, don't use antMatcher, if you have only one filter chain.

I needed to switch to make it work:
authz.requestMatchers("/some/endpoint").permitAll()
     .anyRequest().authenticated()

to
authz.requestMatchers("/some/endpoint").authenticated()
     .anyRequest().permitAll()

A cleaner way (as suggested by @KenS) is to create two security beans:
@Order(0)
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain secureEndpoint(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .securityMatcher("/secure-endpoints/**")
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
            )
            .addFilterBefore(new CustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .build();
}

@Order(1)
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain openEndpoints(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).securityMatcher("/open-endpoints/**")
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().permitAll()
            )
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .build();
}


That is not equivalent though. Take a look at securityMatcher as a replacement for antMatcher. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html#use-new-security-matchers for examples. If you only have a single SecurityFilterChain bean, your solution should work as well though.

I only have one SecurityFilterChain bean. I can see that it works. I would like to learn how it would work correctly (like original setup). Would I need 2 beans, one for protected and one for open endpoints?

That's how I would do it, but your solution is fine for your example. You could have your current SecurityFilterChain with http.securityMatchers("/some/endpoint").authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated()) and a second one without securityMatchers and authz.anyRequest().permitAll(). Make sure you add @Order(...) annotations do both beans to define their order (lower number takes priority). For more complex configurations, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity_instances as a start.

The biggest benefit for using multiple SecurityFilterChain beans is when you need to have different authorization mechanisms for different entpoints. You could secure your "/some/endpoint" with your CustomFilter, "/another/endpoint" with oauth2, use basic auth for actuator, and a "denyAll" for everything else.

@KenS I've updated the solution with your suggestion. I tried it and it works. I like it much better.
